# ~/.inputrc is missed in ubuntu 14.04 => Cannot create a key binding

Tags: 14.04, bash, shortcut-keys

I want to add this key binding in the suitable conf file :

```
Control-t: "top -Ss \C-m"
```

Which means : Bind `Ctrl+T` keys to `top -Ss` command line .

---

i enter on terminal `sudo ls ~/.inputrc` to check existence of this conf file . i get this error:

```
 No such file or directory
```

Where can i put this  binding. What is the target file with the new FS hierarchy of Ubuntu14.04 .

Comment: You can create the file and add it there.

Comment: Not "can". You need to create that file and add it there ;)

Comment: And what is the recommended permission for that file : r ?w ?x ? sticky bit ?..so on

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, i had to drop the `=` chmod --reference ~/.bashrc ~/.inputrc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do this to create it with the same access rights as .bashrc:

```
touch ~/.inputrc
chmod --reference=~/.bashrc ~/.inputrc
```

### NOTE :

> **--reference** : it inherits permissions of specified file .

Comment: Oh , great. i like this inheritance of permission using --reference option . thx